# Is Google Identity Platform authentication more vulnerable than traditional HTTP only cookies?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-identity

I am trying to wrap my head around the authentication architecture of serverless web applications using a solution such as Firebase and Google Identity Platform (GIP). In server-based architectures, we typically set an HTTP only cookie with the authentication details, which prevents XSS attacks or malicious chrome extensions from reading this information.

In my experiments with GIP, I noticed the SDK stores the response from GIP in IndexedDB, and it's straightforward to extract the access token, refresh token, and other useful user details. If I understand correctly, actors with access to these tokens can impersonate the user.

Doesn't this make this approach more vulnerable than its server-based counterpart if code injection is a viable attack vector?

**EDIT**

I found [this article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies) in the official documentation that discusses the benefits of HTTP only session cookies over ID Tokens and shows how to create them.

Comment: 1) If the client browser is subject to code injection, then nothing is secure in the browser. 
2) Yes, tokens can permit user impersonation. Since those tokens are OAuth they have short lifetimes (3,600 seconds). 3) OIDC Identity Tokens have an audience that restricts their usage to a single service. 4) Do you have a proof of concept extracting those tokens and using them elsewhere?

Comment: 5) There are many writeups about the strengths and weaknesses of cookies and IndexedDB. Understanding the security weaknesses requires clearly identifying the environment. I recommend that you move this question to Stack Exchange Information Security: https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: +1 to everything John said (and which I'd love to see him post in an answer ). If you're considering the angle where a user can sign in and then use *their* code against your application, have a look at Firebase [App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check) and its server-side [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules).

Comment: Thank you very much John for this answer (and many others!). This all makes sense. Yes, I have a proof of concept (POC) of extracting the Access token (js code) and then using it with a cURL to call the REST endpoint. The POC allows creating a document protected by security rule that guarantees `request.auth.uid == uid`, which I verified to work as expected. The refresh token is also extracted, so the 3600s lifetime is not a hurdle. The audience shouldn't be a hurdle - Google sets it to be the project, so I believe all firebase services should be accessible.

Comment: I get that XSS attacks are very bad in any case. If I'm not mistaken, in the HTTP-only cookie case an attacker's access is contained to the data and services on the compromised page. It seems that with Firebase / GIP, a successful code injection on any page can lead to gaining access to all resources the user is allowed to interact with on Firestore and Storage.

Comment: Thank you Frank. I bumped into the nice intro videos by Google on App Check, so I definitely intend to check it out.

Comment: @AmitA Could you post your solution as an answer so that other's could spot the workaround easier?

Comment: @AmitA I have provided an answer as [community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki). please check

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, by john hanley in the comment above please move this question to Stack Exchange Information Security

1. If the client browser is subject to code injection, then nothing is secure in the browser.
2. Yes, tokens can permit user impersonation. Since those tokens are OAuth they have short lifetimes (3,600 seconds).
3. OIDC Identity Tokens have an audience that restricts their usage to a single service.
4. Do you have a proof of concept extracting those tokens and using them elsewhere?
5. There are many writeups about the strengths and weaknesses of cookies and IndexedDB. Understanding the security weaknesses requires clearly identifying the environment. I recommend that you move this question to Stack Exchange Information Security: [security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/)

Also as frank suggested, have a look at [Firebase App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check) and its server-side [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules).